# Nginx: Change value of `ssl_verify_client` based on request IP

Tags: nginx, openresty, client-certificate

When setting up nginx with client-certificate config, `ssl_verify_client` should be set to `on` or `optional`. If we want to bypass verification for local users (like 192.168.0.0/24), we can use `optional` value. But this way, nginx still requests a certificate from browser and browser will show a prompt to user (if a signed certificate installed on browser).

[image: Client-Certificate browser prompt]

How we can eliminate this popup for local IPs? (even using `lua` module?). Can we set the value of `ssl_verify_client` based on IP (e.g. with a map)? (Can be a `ssl_verify_client_by_lua` or not?)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old questions, but this article was a top hit of google search when I try to find out the same question's answer.

Seems like Nginx team doesn't want to do it based on this answer.

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/317